# Running Microsoft Flow from a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, ms-flow

i have created a Request/Response MS Flow to send email, when i try to call it via Postman i am getting following error.

```
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Send_an_email' inputs at line '1' and column '1411': 'The template language expression 'triggerBody()['emailaddress']' cannot be evaluated because property 'emailaddress' doesn't exist, available properties are 'emailadress, emailSubject, emailBody'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'
```

I have followed following tutorial. http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-run-a-microsoft-flow-from-a-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/

Any help ??

Comment: Have a look this.  I had a similar issue when I tried to use a sub function and apparently instead of TriggerBody() I should be using Item(). https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Manipulating-values-in-Actions/m-p/33384#M3090

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a typo in the JSON payload being sent to the flow. The flow is expecting a property called "emailaddress" but is receiving a property called "emailadress" instead.